# size mentioned in MAT and cached memory for Android APP

Tags: android, android-memory

I have run the MAT in eclipse for checking the memory leakage. I have attached the below report. I could see the size as 11.1 MB.

1. I need to know whether this is the healthy number for all the normal android phones ?
2. After I run the App in my phone, I checked the App cached memory in my phone settings->Apps->Running->show cached processes. It is shown as 20 MB. Why it is so? Is it fine to delete the cache programmatically when we come out of the APP?

[image]

Comment: your first question does not make sense. What is the "App cached memory in settings" and in which way are related with the MAT tool

Comment: Both are 2 separate question . I need to know if these are related and if so how ? . Please clarify

Comment: Mat takes a snapshot of the memory usage while you use your application. The dominato tree will tell you of which is retained more memory. If for instance you are expection to have only a instance of ExampleActivity in the particular moment and you find more than one, than you could have a Memory leak. There is no healthhy number. For the second question I will leave that choice to Android.